# Как получить нужные значения?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, парсер, bs4

Есть код

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(map, 'lxml')
items = soup.find_all('div', class_='map-icon house-for-sale')
```

выводит строки по типу:
`<div class="map-icon house-for-sale" data-html="true" data-original-title="&lt;div class='text-center'&gt;№ 98&lt;br&gt;&lt;br&gt;Стоимость: 400000 $&lt;/div&gt;" data-toggle="tooltip" style="top:947.992px;left:1074.047px;background:url(/images/house_1.gif)" title=""></div>`

```
Пытался 

for x in items:
    s = x.find('div', class_='text-center')
```

Но ничего не находит. Суть в том, чтобы получить значения '№' и 'Стоимость'.
Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: Значение, что вы хотите вытащить увидел в атрибуте `data-original-title`. Оно там как кусок html хранится. Я мог бы и по вашему коду накидать пример извлечения, но лучше добавьте в вопрос ссылку/html чтобы с ней можно было поиграться

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Значение, что вы хотите вытащить увидел в атрибуте data-original-title. Оно там как кусок html хранится.

Поэтому, чтобы его извлечь как текст, нужно его распарсить:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


html = """
<div class="map-icon house-for-sale" data-html="true" data-original-title="&lt;div class='text-center'&gt;№ 98&lt;br&gt;&lt;br&gt;Стоимость: 400000 $&lt;/div&gt;" data-toggle="tooltip" style="top:947.992px;left:1074.047px;background:url(/images/house_1.gif)" title=""></div>
<div class="map-icon house-for-sale" data-html="true" data-original-title="&lt;div class='text-center'&gt;№ 98&lt;br&gt;&lt;br&gt;Стоимость: 500000 $&lt;/div&gt;" data-toggle="tooltip" style="top:947.992px;left:1074.047px;background:url(/images/house_1.gif)" title=""></div>
<div class="map-icon house-for-sale" data-html="true" data-original-title="&lt;div class='text-center'&gt;№ 98&lt;br&gt;&lt;br&gt;Стоимость: 600000 $&lt;/div&gt;" data-toggle="tooltip" style="top:947.992px;left:1074.047px;background:url(/images/house_1.gif)" title=""></div>
"""


soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
items = soup.find_all('div', class_='map-icon house-for-sale')

for x in items:
    data_original_title = x['data-original-title']
    print(data_original_title)

    title_el = BeautifulSoup(data_original_title, 'lxml')
    print(title_el.get_text(strip=True, separator='\n'))

    print()
```

Результат:

```
<div class='text-center'>№ 98<br><br>Стоимость: 400000 $</div>
№ 98
Стоимость: 400000 $

<div class='text-center'>№ 98<br><br>Стоимость: 500000 $</div>
№ 98
Стоимость: 500000 $

<div class='text-center'>№ 98<br><br>Стоимость: 600000 $</div>
№ 98
Стоимость: 600000 $
```

Comment: спасибо.  Можно пояснение, что происходит в data_original_title = x['data-original-title']? Не могу понять, как это работает.

Comment: @alexsandr8433, `data-original-title` это атрибут в теге и в нем был кусок html кода, который сайт через javascript вытаскивает и размещает на странице (рендеринг). Хз зачем это было сделано, мб чтобы сложнее было парсить, мб это костыль фреймворка, мб чьи-то кривые руки :)